# How to pass parameter to webhook telegram bot PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Is it possible send other variables with sendMessage method to webhook?

for example setting the todo variable:

```
function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $azione = $message['todo'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  $firstname = isset($message['chat']['first_name']) ? $message['chat']['first_name'] : "";
  $lastname = isset($message['chat']['last_name']) ? $message['chat']['last_name'] : "";

  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    $text = $message['text'];
    if (strpos($text, "/start") === 0) {
    apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Benvenuto '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' sul BOT di MIMANCHITU, dimmi cosa vuoi fare ['.$azione.']?', 'todo' => "fai qualcosa", 'reply_markup' => array(
        'keyboard' => array(array('/consulta', '/guide')),
        'one_time_keyboard' => true,
        'resize_keyboard' => true)));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't send any other variable other than what is defined in the documentation.

Comment: and so, if I would make a question depending the user answer?
For example is possible send variable by custom button keyboard?

Comment: @DigitalXP I don't understand what you mean by variable. You can use inline buttons or custom keyboard to provide user with a set of pre defined command.

Comment: I make an example: I would make a bot to search word into db. I start with two keyboard option SEARCH INTO A | SEARCH INTO B. When user click on search INTO A insert a word and then the bot search into DB A, but when the user click into SEARCH INTO B, the bot repeat searching into db A beacuse usign php I only check the sendMessage by the text type! So I would pass a kind of parameter when user click to A or B!

Comment: @DigitalXP Send two buttons "SEARCH INTO A" and "SEARCH INTO B". when user click on one, ask user to send you the search query. Store the query in database or cache for that user and send back the search result with two buttons again. If user clicked on another button (e.g SEARCH INTO B) check if you have a stored query,